# Class for Counting frequency of numbers in a interval

Tags: c++, frequency, frequency-distribution

I need to build a bar gragh that illustrate a distribution of pseudorandom numbers that determined by linear congruential method

```
Xn+1 = (a * Xn + c) mod m
U = X/m
```

on the interval [0,1]

For example:
Interval           Frequency

```
[0;0,1]            0,05
[0,1;0,2]          0,15
[0,2;0,3]          0,1
[0,3;0,4]          0,12
[0,4;0,5]          0,1
[0,5;0,6]          0,15
[0,6;0,7]          0,05
[0,7;0,8]          0,08
[0,8;0,9]          0,16
[0,9;1,0]          0,4
```

I have written such a program

lcg.h:

```
class LCG {
public:
    LCG();
    ~LCG();
    void setSeed(long);
    float getNextRand();
    void countFrequency();
    void printFrequency();

private:
    vector<int>frequencies;
    long seed;
    static const long a = 33;
    static const long c = 61;
    static const long m = 437;
};
```

lcg.cpp:

```
void LCG::setSeed(long newSeed)
{
    seed = newSeed;

}



LCG::LCG() {
    setSeed(1);

}

LCG::~LCG() { }

float LCG::getNextRand() {
    seed = (seed * a + c) % m;
    return (float)seed / (float)m;
}

void LCG::countFrequency()
{


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        frequencies[i] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        float u = getNextRand();
        int r = ceil(u * 10.0);
        frequencies[r] = frequencies[r] + 1;
    }
}

void LCG::printFrequency()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        const float rangeMin = (float)i / 10.0;
        const float rangeMax = (float)(i + 1) / 10.0;
        cout << "[" << rangeMin << ";" << rangeMax << "]"
            << " | " << frequencies[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    LCG l;
    l.countFrequency();
    l.printFrequency();
}
```

It compiles and lint properly, but do not want to run. I have no idea what is wrong with my program. something wrong with functions countFrequency and printFrequency. But I can not figure out what. Maybe you know?

Comment: Is that your full program? If so: you need a `main` function. If not, can you clarify the problem? How do you compile it? What do you mean by saying it does "not want to run"? What happens when you try to run it?

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger? What happens then?

Comment: 1. `frequencies` is not sized correctly, 2. Use `double` not `float`, 3. Ditch that destructor. Let the compiler use the default one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is wrong:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    frequencies[i] = 0;
```

At this point your `frequencies` is empty, and you can't access it's elements like this: the index is out-of-bounds, which is causing the crash. To populate the vector, use `push_back()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    frequencies.push_back(0);
```

Other minor stuff:

- your constructor does too much work:

  ```
  LCG::LCG() {
      setSeed(1);    
  }
  ```

  the proper way would be to use initializer lists: `LCG::LCG() : seed(1){ }`
- If you don't do anything special in the destructor, don't define it at all, let the compiler do it for you.
- Use `double` instead of `float` for some extra precision; `ceil` operates `double`s anyway.